# Classifying lists with inner lists

Tags: ios, swift, generics, filter, sequence

I have 3 Models in the following structures

```
class Option {
    var id       : String  = ""
    var quantity : Int = 0

    init(_id: String, _quantity: Int) {
        id = _id
        quantity = _quantity
    }
}

class RemovedItems {
    var id       : String  = ""
    var quantity : Int = 0

    init(_id: String, _quantity: Int) {
        id = _id
        quantity = _quantity
    }
}

class ProductOrder {
    var guid    : String = ""
    var sizeHid : String = ""
    var options : [Option] = []
    var removed : [RemovedItems] = []

    init(id: String, sizeId: String, _options: [Option], removedItems: [RemovedItems]) {
        guid    = id
        sizeHid = sizeId
        options = _options
        removed = removedItems
    }
}
```

Now i have a list of ProductOrder

> [ProductOrder]

I want to filter this list by the options and removed lists.

> productOrder1 has options list with [A1, A2], and removed with [C1]
>
> productOrder2 has options list with [A1, A2], and removed with []
>
> productOrder3 has options list with [A1], and removed with [C1]
>
> productOrder4 has options list with [A1, A2], and removed with [C1]

so the result will show that the productOrder1, productOrder4 is the same because they have the same options and removed lists.

I can accomplish this with just looping over the array and using some logic, but i want to be able to do that with higher order functions and sequences. In short I want to clean my code a little bit. So, how can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution based on `Equatable` and `forEach`, one shot filtering:

**model**

```
class Option: Equatable {
  var id       : String  = ""
  var quantity : Int = 0

  static func == (lhs: Option, rhs: Option) -> Bool {
    return lhs.id == rhs.id
  }

  init(_id: String, _quantity: Int) {
    id = _id
    quantity = _quantity
  }
}

class RemovedItems: Equatable {
  var id       : String  = ""
  var quantity : Int = 0

  static func == (lhs: RemovedItems, rhs: RemovedItems) -> Bool {
    return lhs.id == rhs.id
  }

  init(_id: String, _quantity: Int) {
    id = _id
    quantity = _quantity
  }
}

class ProductOrder: Equatable {
  var guid    : String = ""
  var sizeHid : String = ""
  var options : [Option] = []
  var removed : [RemovedItems] = []

  static func == (lhs: ProductOrder, rhs: ProductOrder) -> Bool {
    return lhs.options == rhs.options && lhs.removed == rhs.removed && lhs.guid != rhs.guid
  }

  init(id: String, sizeId: String, _options: [Option], removedItems: [RemovedItems]) {
    guid    = id
    sizeHid = sizeId
    options = _options
    removed = removedItems
  }
}
```

**test**

```
var orderProducts = [ProductOrder]()
let o1 = Option(_id: "o1", _quantity: 1)
let o2 = Option(_id: "02", _quantity: 1)
let r1 = RemovedItems(_id: "r1", _quantity: 1)
orderProducts.append(ProductOrder(id: "if3gpfubicurnwbviprgrv", sizeId: "_1234", _options: [o1, o2], removedItems: [r1]))
orderProducts.append(ProductOrder(id: "if3gpfubicurnwbviprgrb", sizeId: "_1234", _options: [o1, o2], removedItems: [r1]))
orderProducts.append(ProductOrder(id: "if3gpfubicurnwbviprgrc", sizeId: "_1234", _options: [o2], removedItems: []))
orderProducts.append(ProductOrder(id: "if3gpfubicurnwbviprgrd", sizeId: "_1234", _options: [o2], removedItems: []))
orderProducts.append(ProductOrder(id: "if3gpfubicurnwbviprgrj", sizeId: "_1235", _options: [o2], removedItems: [r1]))

var results = [[ProductOrder]]()
orderProducts.forEach {
  if let lastValue = results.last?.last, lastValue == $0 {
    results[results.count - 1].append($0)
  } else {
    results.append([$0])
  }
}
print(results)  //[[1,2], [3,4], [5]]
```

Comment: This solution seems promising, but the results not correct, in the test code you provided, I want to p1, p3 to be matched. Not p1, and p2.
Because p1 and p3 have the same options, and removed lists.

Comment: I see. Edited, check now

Comment: Still wrong, it shows all the the list now, BTW here is my test data.

let o1 = Option(_id: "o1", _quantity: 1)
let o2 = Option(_id: "02", _quantity: 1)
let r1 = RemovedItems(_id: "r1", _quantity: 1)

Comment: orderProducts.append(ProductOrder(id: "if3gpfubicurnwbviprgrv", sizeId: "_1234", _options: [o1, o2], removedItems: [r1]))
orderProducts.append(ProductOrder(id: "if3gpfubicurnwbviprgrb", sizeId: "_1234", _options: [o1, o2], removedItems: [r1]))
orderProducts.append(ProductOrder(id: "if3gpfubicurnwbviprgrc", sizeId: "_1234", _options: [o2], removedItems: []))
orderProducts.append(ProductOrder(id: "if3gpfubicurnwbviprgrd", sizeId: "_1234", _options: [o2], removedItems: []))
orderProducts.append(ProductOrder(id: "if3gpfubicurnwbviprgrj", sizeId: "_1235", _options: [o2], removedItems: [r1]))

Comment: It should first and second items matches, and third item matches with fourth item

Comment: let me try your test

Comment: I tried your test. I get a result with 4 products: // 1, 2, 3, 4. Number 5 is being discarded because doesn't have a matching. Is it wrong?

Comment: Yes, It should be return a list of 3 items
first item: is a list of 1, and 2
second item: is a list of 3, and 4
third item: is 5

Comment: Ok, so as a result you want to have a collection of sets, right?

Comment: because if you notice 1,2 have the same list for options and removed items, and number 3, and 4 have the same options and removed items lists, and number 5 does not match any of them. So, i expect a result of a list has 3 items like so;
[ [1,2], [3,4], [5]  ]

Comment: Ok, let me try to make different sub arrays

Comment: Edited. Try now, I am getting [ [1,2], [3,4], [5] ]

Comment: This is perfect, Thank you a lot. Beers on me :)